# Errors in installing facebook sdk

Tags: javascript

I am trying to install facebook sdk for my website but I am getting this error, could any one please help me?

[image]

Here is the code snippet I used.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
        FB.init({
            appid: 322315014798595,
            version: 'v2.8'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Where's the end of `$(document).ready(function(){`?